# Conway's Game OF Life maximum periods on a set x by x game board.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory, recursion, combinatorial-game-theory, cellular-automata

I have taken interest in [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) and want to know if you guys can help me with a mathematical problem :) That is what this website is for right?

You need to be familiar with the rules of his game before answering this question I suppose.

Simply put, I want to figure out how many generation repetitions are possible on a give X by X game board.

Let me make a simplified example. We will use a number from 0-9 to represent each generation. Now let's say that we run the program and it calculates generation after generation. After 10 generations we have this historical data of the generations calculated: 5,3,8,6,1,9,4,5,2,6.  This data contains no stagnation yet. Let's continue:
5,3,8,6,1,9,4,5,2,6,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,8. No this data contains stagnation that involves 2 generations repeating. Here is data that involves 3 generations repeating: 6,4,2,7,4,6,7,4,6,7,4,6. And 4 generations repeating: 3,6,3,8,9,2,0,5,2,9,0,5,2,9,0,5,2,9.

In a real 8 by 8 matrix we can represent the whole matrix using 8 integers holding an integer from 0-255 each representing one row of the matrix. Like this: {230,100,034,010,178,234,098,111} One of these represents one number in my simplified answer. So if I make an example using this form for a stagnation of 2 then it looks like this (notice that I only change the second row):
{230,100,034,010,178,234,098,111}
{230,101,034,010,178,234,098,111}
{230,100,034,010,178,234,098,111}
{230,101,034,010,178,234,098,111}

So again, is it possible to figure out what is the maximum stagnation period possible on a X by X game board?

I am not sure what tags should be associated with this question. Feel free to suggest some.

Comment: You will want to study https://oeis.org/A231427 and http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/List_of_common_oscillators

Comment: I see.. 
So for example, if I find that an oscillator with a period more that 9 requires bigger grid than 16 by 16 then I can assume that the periods will always be 9 or under. Correct?

Comment: I think those sources give an oscillator of period 15 on a $10\times10$ grid, but, really, I didn't look into the question in any detail (that's for you to do).

Comment: I asked this question here because the math behind it is to advanced for me. 
The alternative is to actually use sources like @GerryMyerson pointed towards to see which known oscillators fit into X by X (whichever size I want) game board and then account for the highest period of those. 
For example: if we pick a 16 x 16 game board then, with the list provided, we can see that we need to account for up to period 15 since the Pentadecathlon has a bounding box of 16 x 9. 
A more exhaustive list would be better.
Here is another list: http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Oscillators

Comment: We can construct exponential periods in life. The idea: construct disjoint cyclic paths of different length where something move and take time: 2,3,5,...,p to go back to initial position. Do it in a (kp)x(kp) torus. The temporal period of this pattern will be 2x3x5x...xp, which grows exponentially fast with p.

Comment: Okay.. @user148606

Comment: @user, to do that, you have to know how, for each prime $p$, to construct a configuration of order $p$. I don't even know whether that's possible. But even if it is it doesn't answer OPs question, as OP needs to know how big a box is needed to contain all these configurations.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit sketchy. Take the CA wireworld (or something similar): it is possible to build concentric loops (square shape) of length $8\times 3$, $8\times 5$, ..., $8\times p$ in a configuration of size (roughly) $2p\times 2p$. If you put a particle in each of this loops, you get an exponential period in the size of the configuration. Now back to the question addressed here: Game of Life can simulate any CA using $K\times K$ blocks of cells and with a constant time slow down, therefore the construction for wireworld translates into exponential periods for life.